# Swift: Hold code execution until API response received

Tags: swift, api, concurrency, closures

I need to set up authorization screen:

1) Login and pass is inputted

2) App requests token from API

3) Response is received

4) App checks if response contains token: if contains, should perform authorization

PROBLEM TO SOLVE: app makes 4) before step 3)

What I tried: I used escaping closure in order to hold the execution until API data is received, but it helped only partially - it helped to hold only assignment of value to token, but I cannot hold 'if checks' still.

```
    override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "loginSegue" {

        let login = loginInput.text!
        let password = passInput.text!

        tokenLoader.getToken(login: login, password: password) { [weak self] token in
            self?.token = token.access_token
        }

        //THIS CODE I NEED TO HOLD UNTIL DATA FROM API RECEIVED
        if token != "" {
            return true
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Incorrect password", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
        //

    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

```
    class TokenLoader {
    let session = Session.instance
    let baseUrl = "http://46.254.18.193:9096"

    func getToken(login: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (AccessToken) -> Void) {
        let path = "/token"
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "client_id": login,
            "client_secret": password,
            "scope": "read"
        ]
        let url = baseUrl+path
        AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseData { response in

            do {
                let token = try JSONDecoder().decode(AccessToken.self, from: response.value!)
                print(token)
                self.session.token = token.access_token
                completion(token)

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `shouldPerformSegue` is not a function you can use for async tasks. place the code somewhere else (maybe viewViewLoad of the second ViewController). Move whatever you want to execute after the token call into the closure (where you set the token)

Comment: What triggers the `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`? ie when is called `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender)` for that segue? Make it call it ONCE you get the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve the issue using this function ... perform it on event when you want to segue or to get token

```
func getTokenAndPerformSegue() {
    let login = loginInput.text
    let password = passInput.text

    if let getLogin = login ,let getPassword = password {

    tokenLoader.getToken(login: getLogin, password: getPassword) { [weak self] token in
           self?.token = token.access_token

        if token.isEmpty() {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Incorrect password", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: nil)
        }

       }
    }

}
```

you need to write it like this ... to return nil or error in completion

```
 func getToken(login: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (AccessToken?) -> Void) {
        let path = "/token"
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "client_id": login,
            "client_secret": password,
            "scope": "read"
        ]
        let url = baseUrl+path
        AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseData { response in

            do {
                let token = try JSONDecoder().decode(AccessToken.self, from: response.value!)
                print(token)
                self.session.token = token.access_token
                completion(token)

            } catch {
                completion(nil)
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you did not get anything or you need further help

Comment: Thank you very much for responses! I changed shouldPerformSegue to func (according to above example) and now system holds code until API request is received! But one bug is still in place: in case API response is nil (incorrect password), token.isEmpty() part is not executed

Comment: how you get nil ? in which variable response ?'

Comment: in current implementation you are just getting token

Comment: I receive error in func getToken - in the Catch. The code of this method in the question.